# Assign vector to multiset

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++11, multiset

Is there any good way for assigning std::vector to std::multiset? Other than iteration of course. I see that in C++11 there is something like initializer list, maybe it can be used somehow?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with iterators here?

Comment: @Xeo They are uncomfortable and probably it's not the fastest solution.

Comment: `std::vector<T> vec(set.begin(), set.end())`?

Comment: @user1873947 *you* are uncomfortable with them. FTFY

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes I mean, iteration requires more code than the solution from the answers. You can do it in some lines and you can do it in one line, thats the comfort.

Comment: @Xeo His problem is not "iterators", it is "iteration".

Comment: If you're not "comfortable" doing the iteration yourself, then let the library do it for you, e.g. with [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: @user1873947 The answers use iterators and in a single line do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
vector<int> v;
//fill your vector
multiset<int> m (v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
std::vector<SOME_TYPE> a;
....
std::multiset<SOME_TYPE> ms(a.begin(), a.end());
```